# What would a non-perturbative renormalization group treatment for polymers look like?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, renormalization, non-perturbative

I know that one can do perturbative renormalization for the polymer excluded volume problem or the self-avoiding walk problem corresponding to n=0 component field theory. Here in Hamiltonian, we have, apart, from the quadratic term, an additional effective two-body interaction via delta-function pseudopotential. One can explore tricritical behaviour by adding an extra three-body interaction term. These terms are treated as perturbations to the free Hamiltonian in the RG treatment.

I wanted to know if one can perform a non-perturbative RG for this class of polymer problems and if so, then, how to go about it. Additionally, a list of key literature on such treatments to polymer problems would really help. I tried searching to no avail.